# MySQL 'Update Timestamp' Column - Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm adding a column `tsu` (timestamp update) of type `DATETIME` to a number of my tables.

I need to write `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers that will update the column to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`, but I can't get it right. Tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `cams`.`tsu_update_csi` BEFORE UPDATE
    ON `cams`.`csi`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE csi SET tsu = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE csi_code = OLD.csi_code;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction pls?
MTIA

Comment: You should probably mention in the question that you already have a column of type TIMESTAMP with a default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, to store the record creation time.

Comment: You're right Ian. I didn't understand the implications of multiple TIMESTAMP columns before. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, try this one:

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE  
    TRIGGER `cams`.`tsu_update_csi` BEFORE UPDATE  
    ON `cams`.`csi`  
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
        SET NEW.tsu = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;   
END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that example is what I needed! Understand TIMESTAMP much better now.

Answer (score 16):

If the field can be defined as a timestamp, you can use the following:

> ```
> ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>               ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
> ```

Comment: No, I can't do that, if I keep the original `ts` column:
`    ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it'll work for you, but you can always make it a `TIMESTAMP` field with no default value -- MySQL will automatically set the value of the first such field defined in the table to the current timestamp on every update.

Comment: Thanks Zerofiz and Ian. I already have a column `ts` which is set to default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, as it was intended to represent the "Date Created". From my reading up on TIMESTAMP, it's not possible to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default on one ts column and on update in another column (which is exactly what I really wanted of course).

I'm checking with the client to see if we can use the existing `ts` field as the "Date Updated", and dispense with the "Date Created".

Answer (score 0):

ts2 `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` works for `DATETIME` and TIMESTAMP fields, for one and multiple fields

so you can use  datecreated `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (as the default value)

and dateupdated `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` works for `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` fields (as the default value)

You can use the above as SQL commands or default values in MySQL workbench

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of non-working or incomprehensible examples on the network.
I spent several hours to put together a working example for my EFFCORE CMS.
Here is this example:

**Trigger on UPDATE**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `updated_at__on_update`
BEFORE UPDATE
ON `demo`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET new.updated_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**Trigger on INSERT**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `updated_at__on_insert`
BEFORE INSERT
ON `demo`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET new.updated_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**Table `demo`**

```
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `text` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```