# MySQL how to timestamp only one column update in same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, eventtrigger

Here is my code so far

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER status AFTER UPDATE ON users
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
            IF NEW.status != OLD.status
            THEN INSERT INTO users (status_change_date)
            VALUES (NOW());
            ENDIF;
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

What we are trying to do is to update a field with the current date when that specified field is changed and save that date in that same table under status_change_date. The above code throws errors with MySQL. Its screaming at me that it cannot call itself to update the same table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL 'Update Timestamp' Column - Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045745/mysql-update-timestamp-column-trigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to modify the same table, try with using the `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger instead of `AFTER UPDATE` , like so:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER status BEFORE UPDATE ON users
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
            IF NEW.status != OLD.status
            THEN INSERT INTO users (status_change_date)
            VALUES (NOW());
            ENDIF;
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. We decided to go a different direction and manually update the status_change_date instead of doing it automatically. This was done for other reasons as well. It allowed information to be back-dated when entered in case the status should have been changed at a previous date but wasn't. I am marking your answer as the correct answer to give you credit for helping out.