# inserting mm/dd/yyyy datetime values using trigger

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert US style dates into a table.

```
INSERT INTO mytable BeginDateTime, EndDateTime VALUES ('6/21/1999 9:00 AM', '3/3/2003 3:00 PM')
```

I have tried creating a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `us2isodate` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.BeginDateTime = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.BeginDateTime, '%m/%e/%Y %r');
  SET NEW.EndDateTime = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.EndDateTime, '%m/%e/%Y %r');
END
```

That doesn't seem to work because I think the date is already evaluated as NULL before it's passed to the STR_TO_DATE function.  Is it possible to handle this with a trigger or is it necessary to correctly format the date in or before the insert statement.

Comment: This question has been answered before. [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045745/mysql-update-timestamp-column-trigger)

Comment: @AlanAsher No, this one differs.

Comment: So, are those date/time fields actually string (varchar) fields?

Comment: @AlanAsher I edited the question to show that I have a date string already that I want to insert, not that I want to create or update a timestamp.

Comment: @AlanAsher The data is coming from a csv file and I'm writing it to datetime fields.

Comment: Are you able to run some PHP on the input from the file before sending it to the database?  This doesn't sound like a job for a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If the data comes from a CSV file, you don't need a trigger. It also doesn't work with a trigger.

You insert the data with a `LOAD DATA INFILE` command something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/path/to/file.csv" 
INTO TABLE your_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "whatever" 
(col1,@my_date)
SET your_datetime_column = STR_TO_DATE(@my_date, '%m/%e/%Y %r');
```