# How to automaticly update a timestamp on table update?

Tags: mysql, database

I have this table with newspost, i want to add timestamps on date added, and i want to update another col when the post is edited. I would like it to happen automaticly in MySql. without the use of any PHP code.

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      data text,
      date_published timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      date_edited timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

What's the best practice in a case like this?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html

Comment: Could be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045745/mysql-update-timestamp-column-trigger

Comment: Did you at all search SO for a similar question? There are tons actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` features on one timestamp column in a table.

Use the following table definition to turn off the features for date_published and use them for date_edited:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (
   id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   data TEXT,
   date_published TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   date_edited TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```

When inserting a new row, pass a `NULL` value for date_published to automatically assign the current timestamp to that column.

MySQL Docs on [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> It need not be the first TIMESTAMP column in a table that is
>   automatically initialized or updated to the current timestamp.
>   However, to specify automatic initialization or updating for a
>   different TIMESTAMP column, you must suppress the automatic properties
>   for the first one. Then, for the other TIMESTAMP column, the rules for
>   the DEFAULT and ON UPDATE clauses are the same as for the first
>   TIMESTAMP column, except that if you omit both clauses, no automatic
>   initialization or updating occurs.
>
> To suppress automatic properties for the first TIMESTAMP column, do
>   either of the following:
>
> - Define the column with a DEFAULT clause that specifies a constant default value.
> - Specify the NULL attribute. This also causes the column to permit NULL values, which means that you cannot assign the current timestamp by setting the column to NULL. Assigning NULL sets the column to NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using triggers. From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html):

> A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table. Some uses for triggers are to perform checks of values to be inserted into a table or to perform calculations on values involved in an update.

Example of a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_example AFTER UPDATE ON news
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE some_table SET another_column = NEW.data;
```